# Login to Gmail using PHPMailer with a hashed password

Tags: php, security, gmail, phpmailer

I'm  trying to use PHPMailer to send an email to users via Gmail, which required typing out both the username and password of my Gmail account. Everything works fine in my local tests. Problem is, uploading the `.php` file containing my password to the shared hosting service that I'm using seems rather wrong.

First and foremost, is this a valid concern? If so, would it be possible to somehow use a hashed version of my password, so that it could be decrypted by Google?

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: "Is this a valid concern?" Absolutely. All credentials stored in plaintext are. "Would it be possible to somehow use a hashed version of my password." No. However, your application doesn't need your password. Google uses OAuth2 in their APIs. I strongly suggest you use one of their supplied SDKs instead of the SMTP interface. See https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php. But even with SMTP, [use OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol#smtp_protocol_exchange).

Comment: OAuth does have some merits, but bear in mind that OAuth for email is extremely complex, difficult, fragile, and unpleasant to use, especially with gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Management of such secrets is a very common problem. If your server is configured well, it doesn't represent a risk to do this, but you need to ensure that your secrets (which also includes things like your database credentials) are kept *outside* your web root, and preferably outside any git repo you keep your code in. The most common way of doing this is to use a `.env` file that your app reads to load the secrets (usually using [this library](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) for PHP), and you can make sure the location, ownership, and permissions are set appropriately for this file.

There are many other ways to do this, and it's too broad a subject to answer fully here, but [this article gives an overview](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-managing-secrets-safely-with-version-control-systems), and [this article goes into more PHP-specific options](https://jolicode.com/blog/what-you-need-to-know-about-environment-variables-with-php).